# How can I find an Activity with an ActivityDate closest to today?

Tags: apex

If I have a list of Activities (Tasks and Events), and I want to find the closest activity to today, what's the best way to go about doing this? Is there a built in method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT Id,
    (SELECT Id FROM ActivityHistories WHERE ActivityDate != NULL ORDER BY ActivityDate DESC LIMIT 1),
    (SELECT Id FROM OpenActivities WHERE ActivityDate != NULL ORDER BY ActivityDate ASC LIMIT 1)
FROM *object*
```

From here, just compare the difference in dates between each returned value to today.

You could also be more selective by choosing to filter using greater or less than today for each (open activities can be in the past, such as open, past-due tasks), or you could filter by type (event versus task), and so on. Or if you wanted to find just the nearest one in the future, you could remove the additional sub-query, or you could query just for tasks or events, sorted as described above.